# Blender wont export to trainsimulator

Tags: materials

Hi folks ive been using blender for a few years and have made assets for routes ive made in trainsimulator, but since upgrading to 4.0 and then downgrading to 3.5 i can no longer create igs files as briage keeps throwing errors at me. Even just a basic cube with a texture wont export. I will include a screenshot to show what i mean.[image: this is what comes up even with the default cube and a texture]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post images or screenshots of your code, console or error messages. Instead copy-paste the actual text into your post using [proper code tags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), so it can be indexed and searched for, and other users trying to help don't have to type it by hand themselves which is both error prone and time consuming.